# How to save locally rtmp stream on react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ffmpeg

I'm using React Native to display a live stream from RTMP server - and it works great using NodePlayerVideo component from react-native-nodemediaclient.

However, I also need to save that same stream to a local file on the device. How can I do it?

My idea is to use react-native-ffmpeg but it doesn't work.

What is the right ffmpeg command to use? What is the recommended solution?

Comment: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer - as the documentation instruct.

Unfortunately, I discovered that the problem was with the file system setup and not with FFMPEG library. Specifically, for Android I had to use `RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath` and not `RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath` or `RNFS.ExternalCachesDirectoryPath`.

Comment: RanST - we are investigating trying to do exactly this right now. I am interested if you ever managed to get a working solution?

Comment: @Gatmando To save video stream in react native app I used [react-native-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg). The -i argument should be the server from which you can play the stream and the output is simply the absolute path with the file name. Let me know if you have more questions :)